# Sense Hat import error

Tags: gpio, python, pi-2, raspbian-jessie, sense-hat

I made a python program for my Raspberry Pi a while back and it uses my sense hat and motion sensor both connect via gpio by using a TriGpio expansion board and it worked for a while until recently when my power surged during a storm and my pi was on during it. When I booted it back up I went to start the script like normal and I got this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/motion.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sense_hat import SenseHat
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sense_hat/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .sense_hat import SenseHat, SenseHat as AstroPi
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sense_hat/sense_hat.py", line 7, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .polynomial import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 19, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq, inv
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from .linalg import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 29, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite, _umath_linalg
ImportError: /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3: undefined symbol: spotf2_spftrf_`

Can anyone help me fix this without possibly reformatting my sd card?

Comment: Looks like one or more packages that numpy depends on (or numpy itself) are corrupt. You can try reinstalling them with with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-numpy liblapack3 libblas3`

Comment: Can you post it as an answer as to help more people?

Comment: My suggestion was based on what had corrupted on your system (the fact it was in liblapack.so.3 also meant I just happened to be able to guess what packages needed re-installing), which is something quite specific to your scenario. I'd suggest, instead it'd be more useful to link to more general means of [detecting and correcting corrupt packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57682/find-and-reinstall-packages-with-corrupted-files-without-breaking-anything).